# Random Parallax Background without Javascript - possible?

Tags: css

I currently have what I believe is a fake parallax (No javascript). Is there any way to add multiple images and use them at random with the current code, preferably without using Javascript.

```
.parallax { 
/* The image used */
background-image: url("Orville-Background.gif");

/* Set a specific height */
height: 1000px; 

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you dont want to use javascript for the random function, you can use PHP?

Comment: I'm open to PHP, but I've never used it.

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj wot? PHP is a server end processor rather than a browser end processor.Having never used it, it would be unwise for the OP to use it for this trivial case

Comment: @Onennon as "Random" does not appear as a concept in native CSS, you **must** use another system to grab "Random" identifiers. Therefore you can use Javascript or something like PHP , at a stretch but by far Javascript would the way this *should* be done.

Comment: Yeah sure, in this case javascript shoud do its job, if you wan't to keep on changing the images on and on, javascript does its job.